# Javascript link to LIGHTBOX images

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I want add images to my lightbox gallery using javascript links. 
for example, I tried,

```
<script>
imageArray =[
"image1.jpg",
"image2.jpg",
"image3.jpg"
];

function assignUrl(img_num)
    {
        return "www.website/images/" + imageArray[img_num];
    }
</script>
```

And in my gallery, I used,

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.href=assignUrl(0);"  
data-lightbox="imagegallery" >
<img src="javascript:document.location.href=assignUrl(0);" <!-- thumbnail-->        
</a>
```

But it doesn't work.. The thumbnail doesn't show, and when u click, the image keeps loading but nothing happens.

When I use a test link like this, It displays the image.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.href=assignUrl(0);"> TEST </a>
```

Please help? what am I doing wrong? Is there any other workaround this?

Comment: You can not write javascript code in the src attribute of an img :  <img src="javascript:document.location.href=assignUrl(0);">.

Comment: then how can I do it?

Comment: are you using Lightbox or Lightbox2 ? and what are you exactly trying to do? dynamicaly create an image gallery for a custom array of photos "image array" ?

Comment: Using LightBox 2 of corse.

yes dynamic gallery using an array of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an example function to dynamically create and append a and img elements based on the imageArray variable. Then activated the plugin by calling lightbox function.

I didnt want to touch your code as much as possible.

Here how it looks:

```
<script>
    imageArray =[
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg"
    ];

    function assignUrl(img_num)
    {
        return "www.website/images/" + imageArray[img_num];
    }


    $(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
            var div = $("<a/>").attr("href",assignUrl(i)).attr("data-lightbox","imageGallery");
            div.append($("<img/>").attr("src",assignUrl(i)).attr("width","20%").attr("height","20%"));
            console.log($);
            $("body").append(div);    
        }
        $('a[rel="lightbox"]').lightBox();
    });

</script>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/jTDk9/7/

Comment: Thank you... But where do I call this function?
I mean what about the HTML? can u help please..

Comment: I am appending the images directly to body element. if you for example have <div id="imageGal"></div> in your body, you can append to this div by changing $("body").append(div);  to $("#imageGal").append(div);. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/jTDk9/3/

Comment: ooh.. thanx alot.. 
 1 more thing, Can you tell me how to add the attrbs Width = 20% and height=20% to the img src ?

Comment: 20% height and width are still the same :|